# Is there any cons of creating subsites in Sharepoint WCM senario for Public facing site

Tags: wcm

In my current project we have to implement navigation till third level so I thought of utilizing subsites. They don't want to have subsites instead they want on page Library and create a navigation.  I dont see any cons of creating subsite is there is any disadvantges of Sharepoint subsites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would even advise to work with subsites to create your navigation structure. Using subsites, it's very easy to group information that belongs in one place, and provides even easier use to display context-sensitive content in a content by query webpart.

It's also interesting to use for seo-purposes, because you can make site names descriptive for the content that resides in those sites.

Comment: Thanks Bas even i dont see any downside of it but at my work some people are against it.

Comment: ask them "why". Get to know why they see the downside from it. Convince them. say a pray and even convert them if needed ;)

Answer (score 2):

No it's very common for WCM to use a lot of subsites